# How can i change the color of equal to sign "=" in eclipse or aptana theme

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana3

I am using Eclipse with aptana plugin as my IDE. I know that in Aptana theme i can chnage the color of functions , variables etc.

But how can change the color of `"="`

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio 2 -  Go to General > Editors > Text Editor

There is a box that says - Appearance Color Options

Click on - Foreground Color

Uncheck the "use system default" box (if its checked)

Select a new color.   This will change the = sign color.